# Python tkinter: Aligning multiple labels & text boxes using Pack manager

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, label, pack

**Python 3.5.1
Is it possible for a label beside a text box in a row then another label beside another text box in another row & the labels should be aligned as well as the text boxes?
I already tried it with the grid manager and it worked but my professor wanted us to use the pack manager and I don't know how to align them.
[Expected Output //Using Pack manager but I created this with the grid manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct7n6.png)

I think it had got to do with the sequence of my packages and the anchor & side. When i used the side='top' to manipulate the 1st label so that the 2nd label below it should be aligned, the 1st text box can't be aligned by row on the 1st label. But when i will use either anchor='n' or 'ne', 1st label & 1st text box worked fine but the 2nd label stayed in line with the 1st one. 
[Here is the current code i'm working at (I can't paste it on the code sample)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE1CZ.png)

Thank you for helping!

( I already got the answer thanks for the help! I used frames for controlling the labels & textboxes.)

Comment: hint: this will only be possible if you use some extra frames. For example, put each label/entry combination in its own frame.

Comment: To have the entry boxes line up, the labels need a width large enough to hold the longest label.